# check whether key-value present in any object in array (array of object)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have array of object as

```
$a = [{"id":"20","invoice_id":"123"},{"id":"21","invoice_id":"123"},{"id":"22","invoice_id":"125"},{"id":"23","invoice_id":"125"},{"id":"24","invoice_id":"123"}];
```

here i want to create new array of abject in which duplicate object will not be there (`invoice_id`) as new array will be having first object of same `invoice_id`. i was doing like this.

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($new)) {
            foreach ($new as $k => $val) {
                if($val->id != $value->id) {
                    $new[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $new[] = $value;
        }
    }
```

my new array will be like

```
$new = [{"id":"20","invoice_id":"123"},{"id":"22","invoice_id":"125"}]
```

but it is not giving desired output . What should be done ?

Comment: What is `$new`?

Comment: $new will be that new array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this as Laravel question use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby).

Less code (one line!) and performance hit is non-existent.

```
$a = json_decode('[{"id":"20","invoice_id":"123"},{"id":"21","invoice_id":"123"},{"id":"22","invoice_id":"125"},{"id":"23","invoice_id":"125"},{"id":"24","invoice_id":"123"}]');

$result = collect($a)->groupBy('invoice_id');
```

---

After OP edited question:

```
$result = collect($a)->unique('invoice_id')->values()->toArray();
```

results in:

```
=> [
     {#826
       +"id": "20",
       +"invoice_id": "123",
     },
     {#824
       +"id": "22",
       +"invoice_id": "125",
     },
   ]
```

or using `->toJson()` instead of `->toArray()`

```
"[{"id":"20","invoice_id":"123"},{"id":"22","invoice_id":"125"}]"
```

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: After your edit: use `->unique('invoice_id')` instead of `groupBy`, and you can convert it to array via `->toArray()`

Comment: well, my data has changed now but it is showing only one row..which is first one from $a.

Comment: @VishalBorade You need to describe exactly what you want, you provided me `$a` variable and output `$new` variable and they match with what I've given you.

Comment: your answer in perfect as per my question. Thanks but still it is not working for me.. something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks man, i was doing it wrong.. now it is working i made some changes...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code with simple logic,

```
$temp = $new = array();
$b = json_decode($a, true);
foreach ($b as $key => $val) {
  if(!in_array($val['invoice_id'], $temp)) {
    $temp[$val['id']] = $val['invoice_id'];
    $new[] = array('id' => $val['id'], 'invoice_id' => $val['invoice_id']);
  }
}

print_r($new);
```

I am just creating a temp array to store only the unique invoice_id to compare in a loop.

It gives the below result,

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
        [invoice_id] => 123
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 22
        [invoice_id] => 125
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $data) {
    $result[$data->id] = $data;
}

var_dump(array_values($results));
```

Comment: it is taking last ocuurence of row or object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = json_decode($a); 

$invoiceid = [];
$unique = [];
foreach ($a as $key => $value) { 
    if(!in_array($value->invoice_id,$invoiceid)) {
        $invoiceid[] = $value->invoice_id;
        $unique[] = $value;
    }

}
    echo $a = json_encode($unique);
```